# How to parse a Pandas DataFrame string in Unreal C++?

Tags: c++, pandas, unreal-engine4

I have a web service, which offers labelled 3d points which were serialized using [Pandas' DataFrame's to_json method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) like so:

```json
{
    "x": {
        "6579": 0.2108709365,
        "1079": -0.7737237811
    },
    "y": {
        "6579": -0.9016159773,
        "1079": -1.2094773054
    },
    "z": {
        "6579": -0.164285481,
        "1079": -1.3477079868
    },
    "label": {
        "6579": 4,
        "1079": 6
    }
}
```

I have an `AHttpActor` class, which can request and print the data to the screen:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include "GameFramework/Actor.h"
#include "Runtime/Online/HTTP/Public/Http.h"
#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "HttpActor.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class UE4CPPEXAMPLE_API AHttpActor : public AActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()
    
public: 
    AHttpActor(const class FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer);

    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    FHttpModule* Http;

    void OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful);
};
```

```cpp
#include "UE4CPPExample.h"
#include "HttpActor.h"
#include "Templates/SharedPointer.h"

AHttpActor::AHttpActor(
    const class FObjectInitializer& ObjectInitializer
)
    : Super(ObjectInitializer)
{
    Http = &FHttpModule::Get();
}

void AHttpActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

    TSharedRef < IHttpRequest, ESPMode::ThreadSafe > Request = Http->CreateRequest();
    Request -> OnProcessRequestComplete().BindUObject(
        this,
        &AHttpActor::OnResponseReceived
    );

    Request -> SetURL("http://localhost:2144/sample?limit=1");
    Request -> SetVerb("GET");
    Request -> ProcessRequest();
}

void AHttpActor::OnResponseReceived(
    FHttpRequestPtr Request,
    FHttpResponsePtr Response,
    bool bWasSuccessful
){
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(1, 2.0f, FColor::Green, Response -> GetContentAsString());
}
```

I am a newcomer to C++ and most of the examples are assuming a list of common objects in the data.
So, I am having a surprisingly hard time with this:

**How do I parse this JSON string to a C++ object and iterate over it, one point (x, y, z, label) at a time?**

To make my request more clear, I want to do the following in C++ instead of Python:

```py
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen

with urlopen('http://localhost:2144/sample?limit=2') as response:
    data_dictionary = json.loads(response.read())

for key in data_dictionary['x'].keys():
    x = data_dictionary['x'][key]
    y = data_dictionary['y'][key]
    z = data_dictionary['z'][key]
    label = data_dictionary['label'][key]

    print((x, y, z, label))
```

Comment: Do you know about https://github.com/nlohmann/json? I use it for tons of my C++ projects. It works just great and is soooo easy to use.

Comment: Hi,  @user17242583! Thanksy that library seems cool. I will consider using it.

Comment: Does `Response->GetContentAsString()` return an `FString`?

Comment: There's also https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson which is apparently super fast, but I've never used it.

Comment: Yes, I think so. When I add `FString eff_string = Response->GetContentAsString();` to my code, it still runs without errors.

Comment: Will `std::string s = TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*eff_string);` work?

Comment: Yes, it will when I also `#include <string>` beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

I've never done Unreal C++ development before, but something like this should work:

```cpp
#include <string>

void AHttpActor::OnResponseReceived(
    FHttpRequestPtr Request,
    FHttpResponsePtr Response,
    bool bWasSuccessful
){
    FString fcontent = Response->GetContentAsString();
    std::string content = TCHAR_TO_UTF8(*fcontent);

    nlohmann::json j = nlohmann::json::parse(content);
    for (const auto &[key, _] : j["x"].items())
    {
        std::string x = j["x"][key];
        std::string y = j["y"][key];
        std::string z = j["z"][key];
        std::string label = j["label"][key];
        // do your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me know if there are any errors. I didn't compile or run this code ;)

Comment: I'd written this question off as *Q: How do I read JSON data? A: With a JSON parser.*, but you've got enough value add to make this worthwhile.

Comment: @user4581301 I would have just ignored this question, like I do many similar ones that look complex and hard to understand, but for whatever reason, I felt like I knew what to write. I searched GitHub a bit for the right function calls here and there, and put together something that probably will help. ;)

Comment: Yes. thanks. This already helps. I also hope that consuming DataFrames is common enough to make this worthwhile. I would have preferred a solution using Unreal's tools though. Now, I am facing the next challenge: Using a third-party library with Unreal. XD That must be another question, though.

Answer (score 0):

I tried parsing the string using [JsonObjectStringToUStruct](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.26/en-US/API/Runtime/JsonUtilities/FJsonObjectConverter/JsonObjectStringToUStruct/). Here is the header:

```cpp
USTRUCT()
struct FLabels
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    FLabels() {}

    UPROPERTY()
    TMap<FString, FString> label;
};

USTRUCT()
struct FXs
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    FXs() {}

    UPROPERTY()
    TMap<FString, float> x;
};

USTRUCT()
struct FYs
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    FYs() {}

    UPROPERTY()
    TMap<FString, float> y;
};

USTRUCT()
struct FZs
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    FZs() {}

    UPROPERTY()
    TMap<FString, float> z;
};


USTRUCT()
struct FDataFrame
{
    GENERATED_USTRUCT_BODY()

    FDataFrame() {}

    UPROPERTY()
    FLabels labels;

    UPROPERTY()
    FXs xs;

    UPROPERTY()
    FYs ys;

    UPROPERTY()
    FZs zs;
};
```

Here is the implementation:

```cpp
    FString fcontent = Response->GetContentAsString();
    GEngine->AddOnScreenDebugMessage(1, 2.0f, FColor::Green, fcontent);
    FDataFrame dataframe;
    FJsonObjectConverter::JsonObjectStringToUStruct(fcontent, &dataframe, 0, 0);

    FLabels labels = dataframe.labels;
    FXs xs = dataframe.xs;
    FYs ys = dataframe.ys;
    FZs zs = dataframe.zs;

    TMap<FString, FString> label = labels.label;
    TMap<FString, float> x = xs.x;
    TMap<FString, float> y = ys.y;
    TMap<FString, float> z = zs.z;
```

However, `dataframe` does not get populated.

Answer (score 0):

Another not-working approach is to use a [TJsonReader](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/API/Runtime/Json/Serialization/TJsonReader/). Here is a stub implementation:

```cpp
    TSharedRef<TJsonReader<>> JsonReader = TJsonReaderFactory<>::Create(Response->GetContentAsString());

    TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> JsonObject;

    if (FJsonSerializer::Deserialize(JsonReader, JsonObject))
    {
        TSharedPtr<FJsonObject> labelField = JsonObject->GetObjectField("label");

        TMap<FString, TSharedPtr<FJsonValue>> values = labelField->Values;

    }
```

This works so far, but I cannot find out how to proceed with operating on the values.